# LetterHead design

Tags: design-principles, designers, lettering

I need the following details please:

- best software to use for a letterhead design
- the letterhead is sent to the client under which format? pdf, word, ...?
- the most known margin details of a letter head
- pricing design without printing

thank you in advance 
best regards

Comment: Hello @Rayane, welcome to SO. Your question is way too broad and opinion based. You might need to visit this page: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/asking. However for starters, any graphics software can do the trick. Best software will depend on your budget and skill set. The 'margin details' will depend on the nature of the header you are trying to make. An example of such software is Adobe Illustrator and sending the client a PDF. you can also extract the PNG designs, layer them into the header section in a word document and send them the word doc too.

Comment: Thank you @iamcastelli for you kind answer, you were helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am full time designer,and I have many letter heads

**The best software for designing letter head design are:**

1. Photoshop
2. illustrator
3. coreldraw

**Letterhead format should be:**

1. It depends if you are going to print letter head separately then you
   should send PDF format
2. If you are going to type something on letter head then you should
   send word template file

For margin details you can visit this link [click here](http://css.paperplaza.net/conferences/support/page.php)

**I am staying in India and I am charging Rs.5000 for one design. Price differs place to place**

Thanks